# What's the latest Stimulsoft Reports version compatible with ASP.NET CORE 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, stimulsoft

Does anyone know what is the latest version of Stimulsoft Reports that is compatible with ASP.NET CORE 2.1? Can anyone please provide a download link to it directly?

The download links at https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/downloads/reports don't provide clear information on which version is compatible with .NET CORE 2.1

Answer (score 1):

I can use Stimulsoft in asp.net core 2.1 after installing the latest **2021.2.4 version** in nuget packages.

To download it, you can click **Visual studio->Tools->NewGet Package Manager**.

Then search and download the stimulsoft package you need:

[image]